why does ida pro bindiff import and comment symbol takes so long compare to the diffing?
so i recently have an ida bindiff result and it got me the matches but when i do import symbols and comments it takes me FOREVER to do like it takes so much longer than the actual diffing
trying to know why bindiff import so long

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
